# Firebase OnDataChange not transitioning to next activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some problems. I want to retrieve the value of the state for order, first, when the Customer creates order the value will add to the firebase "Pending" after that, the customer will wait until Driver accept the order then will change the value from "Pending" to "Accepted".

```
public class C_Offers extends AppCompatActivity {
    String OrderID;
    String phoneNO;
    String State = null;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c_offers);


        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            phoneNO = bundle.getString("Phone");
            OrderID = bundle.getString("OrderID");
        }
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customer").child(phoneNO).child("Order").child(OrderID);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                State = dataSnapshot.child("State").getValue(String.class);
                Toast.makeText(C_Offers.this, "State : "+State, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (State.equals("Accepted")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(C_Offers.this, C_Order.class));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

when use this

```
Toast.makeText(C_Offers.this, "State : "+State, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

will print "Pending", after change the value in Driver side will change and printed "Accepted"

The exact problem is inside this

```
if (State.equals("Accepted")) {
   startActivity(new Intent(C_Offers.this, C_Order.class));
}
```

First not read and close the application, go to back layout
I need to check if value of Firebase is changed to "Accepted" or not
if changed go to new activity this what I want

Comment: so the problem here is it does not go to next activity ?

Comment: Yes, and has crush then go back to last activity

Comment: Can you check the logcat, what does it say?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: I don't know how to do that. @AlexMamo. Is there any other way to do that?  I only need to read value then check if it is "Accepted" go to a new activity only this.

Comment: I found another way is to create a  button and when to click on will check if it is changed or not and it is working but I want this work automatic, Can anyone help me?